# Better performances using Linq and Anonymous Types?

Tags: linq, performance, entity-framework

I use C#, Linq and EF4.

I have a front end for my website, I need display (read only) data from my data base on my web pages.

I would like to know what could help me to achieve faster (read only) results to my users.

Here some idea I'm thinking to implement.

- A - Using Linq and Anonymous Types, so I can select just the proprieties I need to display (using EF) and save some memory. Please tell me if this would increase speed.
- B - Pre compiling my queries.
- C - Have the option tracking off for my objects BojectContext in EF.

Please tell what do you think specially for point A. Thanks for your help!

Comment: imho, nothing is really going to beat SQL + PetaPoco or Dapper here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the functionality working and if you need to optimise then I think the first step is to measure. As a first step, try using SO's profiler to see where your app is consuming time http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

After you've measured, then you can experiment with A, B or C - or you might identify a totally different area to optimise. (My own favorite area for EF optimisation is lazy-loaded sub-objects)

---

Update (in response to comment): Honestly I don't expect A, B or C to gain you any significant time - you need to measure - it's the only way to find out where optimisations can be made. Once you've measured then my guess is that none of A, B or C will save you any significant time at all.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, are you able to give your opinion on the 3 solutions that I would like implement? In your experience what could work best? Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: I've added an update with my opinion - unlike @Janantha I don't think any of A,B or C will provide "great" benefits

Answer (score 0):

I feel all your A,B and C are great and additionally

1. You can have indexes in the database level. If you are using SQL Server you can use Database Tunnig adviser to tune database for your queries.
2. If you use Entity SQL it will be little faster than LINQ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/03/27/ado-net-entity-framework-performance-comparison.aspx

and read this also
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/04/06/improving-entity-framework-performance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous response, first measure the performance.  That will tell you what methods are using up the most processing time.  It is not an efficient use of time to think of new things to use before understanding the issue.  However, it is a great idea to learn new things so that you have more tools.  There will come an appropriate time when you can use your new tools.

ANTS is a great tool to measure performance.  They have good tutorials and it is free for 14 days of usage, plenty of time to find the issues.

You can experiment with the different methods of improvements after you know what needs improvement.